# How to create an array with column => value pairs for $wpdb->insert

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops

I have an array that looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => enrolment_id [1] => 0123) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => child_first [1] => Kate ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => child_last [1] => Limmage ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => child_preferred [1] => )... )
```

etc... all the way to [159].  It comes from $_POST data.

How do I get this to look like

```
'enrolment_id' => '0123',
'child_first' => 'Kate',
'child_last' => 'Limmage',
```

so that I can use it in the from `$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($_POST as $v) {
   $result[$v[0]] = $v[1];
}
```